# ¿Cómo pasar todo el contenido de un DataGridView a otro en un mismo Form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy pasando los datos de una tabla de una base de datos 'Sqlserver' a una tabla de una base de datos 'Mysql' para ello estoy usando un Datagridview que se llene con los datos de la base de datos 'Sqlserver' y el codigo que uso para leer este Datagridview y pasarlo a la base de datos 'Mysql' me pide el nombre de las columnas del Datagridview.

hay mi duda al no saber como se llaman las columnas que se generan automáticamente en el Datagridview con datos de la base de datos 'Sqlserver' e querido pasar de un Datagridview a otro el cual se el nombre de las columnas pero de la manera en que lo logro hacerlo solo se pasa los datos seleccionados y no el contenido completo del Datagridview.

Si saben:

1 El nombre que de las columnas generadas automaticamente ó,
2 pasar todo el contenido del primer Datagridview al otro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data.Types;

namespace DTgrid_a_DTgrid
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Conexion c = new Conexion();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            c.cargarPersonas(dataGridView1);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(new string[] {
                Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value),
                Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value),
                Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[2, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value),
                Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[3, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value)
            });
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection mysqlconexion = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1; database=test_sqlserver; uid=root; pwd=;");

            MessageBox.Show("conexion establesida con mysql");


            MySqlCommand consultagregar = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO persona VALUES(?Id, ?Nombre, ?Apellidos, ?FechaNacimiento)", mysqlconexion);

            mysqlconexion.Open();



            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                {
                    consultagregar.Parameters.Clear();

                    consultagregar.Parameters.Add("?Id", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column1"].Value);
                    consultagregar.Parameters.Add("?Nombre", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column2"].Value);
                    consultagregar.Parameters.Add("?Apellidos", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column3"].Value);
                    consultagregar.Parameters.Add("?FechaNacimiento", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column4"].Value);

                    consultagregar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("Datos agregados " + ex);
                mysqlconexion.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Clase Conexion

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DTgrid_a_DTgrid
{
    class Conexion
    {
        SqlConnection cn;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt;

        public Conexion()
        {
            try
            {
                cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Tutorial;Integrated Security=True");
                cn.Open();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se conecto con la base de datos: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        public string insertar(int id, string nombre, string apellidos, string fecha)
        {
            string salida = "Se se inserto";
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Persona(Id,Nombre,Apellidos,FechaNacimiento) values(" + id + ",'" + nombre + "','" + apellidos + "','" + fecha + "')", cn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                salida = "No se conecto: " + ex.ToString();
            }
            return salida;
        }

        public int personaRegistrada(int id)
        {
            int contador = 0;
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Persona where Id=" + id + "", cn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    contador++;
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo consultar bien: " + ex.ToString());
            }
            return contador;
        }

        public void cargarPersonas(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            try
            {
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Persona", cn);
                dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dgv.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo llenar el Datagridview: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Mas alla que no entiendo el sentido, si igualas los datasources tendrian el mismo contenido...

Comment: hola. mis disculpas soy nuevo, si esta a tu disposición me podrías explicar  eso que acabas de decir es completamente lo que quiero lograr

Comment: El problema con tu pregunta es que no das prácticamente nada de información. Algo muy importante para responderte es, por ejemplo, como estás llenando el Datagridview origen? Añadiendo elementos a la colección items o usando `DataSource`?. Necesitamos ver algo de tu código y que has intentado para poder ayudarte mejor. Te recomiendo que leas los enlaces que te he proporcionado y pulses en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Cómo obtienes tu datasource? si lo tienes wizard tendrías mas problemas a pasar el contenido a un dataTable y de ahí asignarlo a otro gridview, es importante saber como esta tu código para poder ayudarte, ahora me supongo que debes de tener algún tipo de filtro para el gridview2 porque si fuera los mismos datos pues bastaría con replicar lo que haces en el gridview1 con el gridview2, probablemente tengas que recurrir a linq.

Comment: como estas poniendo datos en los DataGridView? porque es muy distinto si usas el Rows.Add() o usar el DataSource

Comment: bueno yo genere el  contenido de el datagridview private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("jhony", "contreras");}

Comment: y lo paso a otro datagridview  por medio de =                                                                    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
dataGridView2.Rows.Add(new string[] { Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value),Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value)
            });
        }                                                                                                             
pero esto solo me pasa el dato que este seleccionando al momento en el primer datagridview

Comment: Como te dije antes,es mejor que pulses en [edit] y mete todo lo que quieras añadir a tu pregunta alli.Es bueno que leas https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE para aprender a formatear el código en tu pregunta.

Comment: ok, re formulare la pregunta para darme a entender mejor :)

Comment: OK. Mas alla que no este bien como lo estas haciendo (pasarle un gridview a un componente de una clase no es sano), estas cargando justamente ese gv desde un datasource. Por lo tanto, si le pasas tambien el gv2 a ese mismo procedimiento c.cargarPersonas(dataGridView2), lo va a llenar exactamente igual. Igual aca el problema esta en otro lado. si vos vas de la Base A a la Base B, obligatoriamente sabes que campo va en cada campo. si no, quien sabe a donde manda cada dato?

Comment: c.cargarPersonas(dataGridView2)  si realizo esta acción me va auto generar unas nuevas columnas el cual no se sus nombres, y si se que campo va en cada campo por que logro subir a la base de datos 'Mysql' esa fila que se carga en el segundo Datagridview, mi pregunta seria cual es el nombre de esas columnas que se auto generan con los datos de la base de datos 'SQLSERVER'

Comment: Para.. la pregunta en realidad es como obtengo el nombre de las columnas de una tabla? o sea, nada que ver con todo esto?

Comment: es una opción, no puedo cerrarme a las posibilidades nadie a sabido responder como pasar todo lo que esta en el primer datagridview al segundo datagridview

Answer (score 2):

Voy a escribir como corregir tu codigo, pero vamos a tener en cuenta varias cosas antes:

- El dgv solamente genera las columnas si tiene la propiedad AutoGenerateColumns en true.
- Si vas a pasar datos de una base de datos a otra, todo esto no tiene sentido.
- Para ir de una base a otra, te alcanza con hacerlo mediante un recordset y despues recorrerlo y mandar los datos a la nueva base.
- En general cuando se va de una DB a otra, ya se sabe de antemano los nombres de las columnas origen y destino. No es magico el pasaje.

Suponiendo que quieras seguir por el camino que vas, tu problema es esta función:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(new string[] {
        Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value),
        Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value),
        Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[2, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value),
        Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[3, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value)
    });
}
```

Ya que estas usando la propiedad CurrentRow, y eso es la fila(s) seleccionada solamente.

Lo que vos tenes que hacer, es recorrer la coleccion filas del dgv1, e ir agregandolas al dgv2.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewRow v in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(new string[] {
            v.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
            v.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
            v.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
            v.Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: en los cells  v.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                    v.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                    v.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                    v.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), me marcan un error que dice : 'Object' no contiene una definicion para 'cells' ni se encuentra ningun metodo de extencion 'cells' que acepte un primer argumento del tipo 'object' (falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado

Comment: @JDvasher tu comentario esta cortado..

Comment: me marca ese error los 4 ´v.Cells[]

Comment: ok. no esta reconociendo a v como un DataGridViewRow.. ahi edito la respuesta. @JDvasher

Comment: Y te aclaro. lo que yo escribi, Ya lo estas haciendo en tu codigo, en otra parte. @JDvasher

Comment: si de una trato de comprender lo que me vas diciendo y lo paso a mi código

Comment: @JDvasher. No, quiero decir, que lo que yo escribi, ya estaba en tu codigo. Ya lo estabas haciendo. Estas pasando fila por fila de tu dgv2 a la base de datos...

Comment: GRACIAS si me funciono ya subio todo a la DB, ya se que no es la manera mas optima peero tenia  esa duda, tienes algun correo donde si puedes me pudieses explicar eso de pasar directamente los datos de una DB a otra DB con el recordset

Comment: anda si es verdad en el mismo código que mostré estaba la solución que loco, otra vez gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @JDvasher Te recomendaria leer al respecto en internet hay montones de tutoriales al respecto. Por lo pronto, te urjo a que si o si leas el [tour], para saber como funciona el sitio.

Comment: ok, empezare a buscar documentación y are el recorrido muchas gracias mi pana.